# How to convert this .htaccess for LIGHTTPD?

Tags: .htaccess, lighttpd

I have this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

How can I convert it to run my website through Lighttpd ?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I think it's not possible without mod-magnet. But maybe someone can prove me wrong. Anyway, this is more for serverfault or superuser.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file => ( ".*" => "/index.php" )
```

Make sure to enable mod_rewrite in lighttpd.conf and reload lighty.

> url.rewrite-[repeat-]if-not-file New:
>   For the 1.4.x branch as of 1.4.24 or
>   r2647 from svn:
>
> Rewrites a set of URLs internally in
>   the webserver BEFORE they are handled
>   and checks that files do not exist.
>
> Take examples from above, this is to
>   mimic Apache´s "!-f" RewriteRule.
>   Please note this does not work for
>   directories, pipes, sockets or alike.
>
> Where do I want to use this? Maybe
>   with e.g. Drupal backend, where
>   mod_magnet (has an Apache´s -f and -d
>   solution) might not be handy or simply
>   "too much" for just this kind of
>   rewrites.